# How to use a Union properly with Order BY?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, union

The code I have below joins 5 tables and then is suppose to sort by date_timed_added.  The query worked perfectly if i only join 4 tables.  For some reason after the 4th table, its giving me issues.  The issue is that it sorts and displays the 5th table first and then the rest follow.  How can i fix it so that it sorts date_time_added properly by querying all the other tables?

```
//$sid is a variable that is drawn from DB

$sql = "select `client_visit`.`visit_id`, `client_visit`.
`why_visit`, `client_visit`.`date_time_added`, `client_visit`.
`just_date`, `client_visit`.`type` from `client_visit` where 
`client_visit`.`system_id` = '$sid' and `client_visit`.
`added_by` = '$sid' 
UNION
select `client_notes`.`note_id`, `client_notes`.`note_name`, 
`client_notes`.`date_time_added`, `client_notes`.`just_date`
, `client_notes`.`type` from `client_notes` where `client_notes`.
`added_by` = '$sid'
UNION
select `client_conditions`.`med_id`, `client_conditions`.`med_name`,  
`client_conditions`.`date_time_added`, `client_conditions`.`just_date`,    
`client_conditions`.`type` from `client_conditions` where 
`client_conditions`.`system_id` = '$sid' and `client_conditions`.
`added_by` = '$sid'
UNION
select `client_stats`.`stat_test_id`, `client_stats`.`stat_why`,  
`client_stats`.`date_time_added`, `client_stats`.`just_date`, 
`client_stats`.`type`
from `client_stats` where `client_stats`.`system_id` = '$sid' 
and `client_stats`.`added_by` = '$sid'
UNION
select `client_documents`.`doc_id`, `client_documents`.`doc_name`,  
`client_documents`.`date_time_added`, `client_documents`.`just_date`, 
`client_documents`.`type` from `client_documents` where `client_documents`.
`system_id` = '$sid' and `client_documents`.`added_by` = '$sid'
 ORDER BY `date_time_added` DESC LIMIT $startrow, 20";

 $query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

 $result = mysql_query($sql);

 if ($result == "")
 {
 echo "";
 }
 echo "";


 $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

 if($rows == 0)
 {

 }
 elseif($rows > 0)
 {
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {

 //Just using these two variables i can display the same row info 
 //for all the other tables

 $stuffid = htmlspecialchars($row['visit_id']);
 $title = htmlspecialchars($row['why_visit');

 }

 }

 }
```

Comment: **Warning** your code maybe vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: How about add some alias, to minify your query?

Comment: They are properly being sanitized.  I didn't put it up there..

Comment: @gabrielsantos not sure why your eyes are hurting! not sure what you mean by alias...

Comment: `SELECT cv.visit_id, cv.why_visit, cv.date_time_added, cv.just_date, cv.type FROM client_visit AS cv WHERE cv.system_id = '$sid' and cv.added_by = '$sid' UNION [...]`

Comment: Cargo cult programming... you do NOT need to escape every single table/field name in your query, and if you're asking about SQL, you do NOT need to include the surrounding PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the MySQL docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

If you want to order the ENTIRE result set, the ORDER BY clause must be placed on the LAST query in the UNION, with each query being bracketed.

```
(SELECT ...)
UNION
(SELECT ...)
ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: Thanks Marc.  I tried it but it still shows me the same results.

Comment: Got it to work by fixing other things.  Works fine for now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

sth like this should do.

```
SELECT Tbl1.field1
    FROM ( SELECT field1 FROM table1
           UNION
           SELECT field1 FROM table2
         ) Tbl1
    ORDER BY Tbl1.field1
```